# Error: no database selected and undefined index

Tags: php

I'm stuck here for almost a day I just can't find the right solution please help I'm getting error that no database is selected but I'm getting the message that the connection is created
the second error I'm getting is undefined index "SNo" "clientname" "contact no" "option-3 (its a checkbox)"

Html form

```
<form  action="survey-data-entry.php" name="1st-form" id="form-control" onSubmit="return validate()" method="post" >    
    <label>S.No.</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" 0451211315" name="SNo" id="s.no"  >
<label>Client Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="clientname" id="clientname" />                
<label>Contact No</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactno" id="contactno" />
    <strong>Pest Buster  </strong>
<input type="checkbox" name="option_3" id="option_3" value="Pest Buster">
```

Here is the PHP code

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username ='root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'survey-form';

$conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(!$conn){
    die("connection failed:" .mysql_error());
}
echo "connection hogya successful";



$SNo = $_POST['SNo'];
     $clientname = $_POST['clientname'];
     $contactno = $_POST['contactno'];
     $option_3 = $_POST['option_3'];
$sql= "INSERT INTO php-startup (SNo, clientname, contactno, option_3)
VALUES('SNo', 'clientname', 'contactno ','option_3')";

if(!mysql_query($sql))
{
die('caution' . mysql_error());
}
echo"1 record added";
```

Comment: check your db name carefully

Comment: Both this code are on same page?>

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions and switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead. People are far more likely to give help if the technology used is current.

Comment: @Akshay survey-form is the name of database and table name is php-startup and no they are on separate pages!!!

Comment: @apokryfos sir i have also used mysqli but error remains

Comment: @Gulshan i had copy paste the name just for my satisfaction but still i didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about that "No database selected", cause I didn't have experience in using `mysql_*`

You could check first if the variables are set or not, like this

```
if(isset($_POST['SNo']))
{
    $SNo = $_POST['SNo'];
    $clientname = $_POST['clientname'];
    $contactno = $_POST['contactno'];
    $option_3 = $_POST['option_3'];
    $sql= "INSERT INTO php-startup (SNo, clientname, contactno, option_3)VALUES('SNo', 'clientname', 'contactno ','option_3')";

    if(!mysql_query($sql))
    {
        die('caution' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo"1 record added";
}
```

That would remove the undefined index errors. And stop using `mysql_*` syntaxes, they are [depecrated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). Instead, study in using `pdo` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

**Database Connection**

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

**Then select db**

```
mysql_select_db('database_name',$connection);
```

**Then Execute Query**

```
if(isset($_POST['SNo'])){
         $SNo = $_POST['SNo'];
         $clientname = $_POST['clientname'];
         $contactno = $_POST['contactno'];
         $option_3 = $_POST['option_3'];
    $sql= "INSERT INTO php-startup (SNo, clientname, contactno, option_3)
    VALUES('$SNo', '$clientname', '$contactno','$option_3')";

    if(!mysql_query($sql))
    {
        die('caution' . mysql_error());
    }
        echo"1 record added";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_connect dose't take database name as parameter [see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).
change->

```
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

->

```
 $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_select_db($database_name, $con)
    mysql_close($con);
```

I will suggest to use mysqli_connect [see documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php).

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database_name);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: it removed my "no database selected " error thanks alot sir